# Identity mechanism for extending access token life

Tags: token, access-token, identity, identityserver4

Is there some mechanism built in Identity for extending access token life, or I have to deal with it ?

Comment: What do you mean by extending it? It has a value that you can change, or you can use refresh tokens to generate a new access token.

Answer (score 0):

When you create a client called [AccessTokenLifetime] this sets how long an access token is valid for.  Normally you would set it to 3600 which is an hour you can of course set it longer.

Once an access token has been created though you cant change its lifetime they have to be created with the desired lifetime.

Remember the point of access tokens is that they are short lived giving them long lifetimes is probably not the best idea.